C++ TBB: How to run multiple `tbb::task_arena` in parallel?
I have a performance critical lambda function p which calculates something and writes its result to an external data structure:
class Foo {
...
  std::vector<int> v;
  auto p = [&]() {
    int res;
    // Calculate and assign to res
    static std::mutex mutex;
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
      v.emplace_back(res);
    }
  }

...
}

Now, I want to call p() in parallel multiple times (say 12 times) on my 48 number of threads. Calls to p() are thread-safe, but very expensive. To minimize overhead on context switching (I'm unsure if this even plays that big of a role), instead of having 12 concurrent p() calls going on at the same time on all 48 threads at once, like in the following:
tbb::parallel_for(0, 12, [](i) {
  p();
});

,
I want to call p() concurrently 12 times, but instead having each call run on only 4 threads. Is there a way for me to achieve this using tbb::task_arena? I would also be open for alternate solutions.
I've tried the following code, but I am not sure if this does what I'm trying to do.
I've looked into documentation of tbb::task_arena but it still isn't clear to me.
std::vector<tbb::task_arena> arenas(12) 
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  arenas[i].initialize(4);
}
tbb::parallel_for(0, 12, [&](int i) {
  arenas[i].execute([&] {
    p();
    std::cout << "Done: " << i << std::endl;
  });
});

